# how to add a param to xslt with xslt-ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, xslt

the title states it, essentially what is wrong here? I keep getting nothingness the param isnt getting passed...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="stylesheet"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$stylesheet"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and heres the ruby code

```
require "rubygems"

require 'xml'
require 'libxml'
require 'libxslt'

xsltdoc = XML::Document.file("main.xslt")
xslt = LibXSLT::XSLT::Stylesheet.new(xsltdoc)

xml = XML::Document.file("file.xml")
result = xslt.apply(xml, {:stylesheet => "style.css"})
puts(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it had something to do with xslt processor, ran it through a saxon soap service and it worked